# Formatting text within a cell

Tags: php, fpdf

I have been instructed to write a script that outputs a contract document as a PDF. The contract template I have been given to use contains blocks of text with bold, italics, and underlines sprinkled throughout otherwise basic strings of times new roman. Currently, I have the contract template in both HTML and MS Doc format.

My first thought was to use the FPDF lib, but FPDF seems to only to be able to draw cells in one text format at a time. Is there a better way to do this?

I found the FPDF Multicell Advanced library, but I'd like to find a solution that doesn't cost before I run to my employer for money.
http://interpid.eu/fpdf-multicell

Comment: You might consider using a doc2pdf tool, instead of trying to write the PDF directly . . .

Comment: This is not a one-time conversion. This script will need to generate PDF contracts on-demand for users with their details filled in using the template I was given.

Comment: I read your question to mean that you were currently generating the docs and the HTML on the fly.  Re-reading the question, you could be saying that your source is doc or html?  In either case, my point is that the PDF generation could be an extension upon the doc generation, whether it's a source or dynamically generated, do that first, then convert the doc to PDF.  For example, a wrapper function that generates the doc, and then converts the generated doc to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

I've had really good success with Zend PDF (Part of Zend Framework)

API Docs Here:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.html

Tutorial Here:
http://devzone.zend.com/1064/zend_pdf-tutorial/

You could repeat the multicell functionality by creating helper classes when you generate the PDF.